# Parse integer from std::string, but fail if float

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++ and C there are multiple methods to convert a string to integer, but I haven't found a conversion method that fails on parsing a floating point number.

```
const float fnum = std::stof("1.5");
std::cout << fnum << std::endl; // prints "1.5", all okay

const int inum = std::stoi("1.5");
std::cout << inum << std::endl; // prints "1", but wrong!
```

I need this to analyse a CSV file for column type. If all fields from one column are integers, then store the column as std::vector< int>, if float, then std::vector< float>, else store it as strings.

The only method that looks promising is this:

```
std::string num = "1.5";
char *end = nullptr;

const long lnum = strtol(num.data(), &end, 10);
if (end != &*num.end()) {
    std::cout << "Float? " << l << " / " << num << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Integer! " << l << " / " << num << std::endl;
}
```

This works, but is quite ugly. Is there a C++-way to solve this?

Comment: [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) have another argument that can be used like the end argument for `strtol`. If you find it "ugly" then how about searching the string to make sure [all](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) characters are [digits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit)?

Comment: @dommynik - Are you sure about `const int fnum`? Isn't `const float fnum`?

Comment: In addition to what Joachim said you can also use a `stringstream` and check if the stream is empty after the conversion call.

Comment: there is no really good way. Either way a) with string parsing. Or b) you use lexical_cast by boost (this should throw exceptions which is kind of ugly) or c) you cast it back to a string afterwards and look if the strings are the same. Ah yeah and stringstreams.

Comment: @max66 thanks and sorry, changed!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks, I would need to look for digit and `+-`, I guess I'll use `std::stoi` since `stringstream`s seem to be quite heavy, and I don't want to use exceptions.

Comment: @dommynik Actually, if you read the `std::stoi` documentation you will see that it *can* throw exceptions, if the string doesn't contain anything it can parse, or if there's an overflow.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ah I see ... I'm currently working with Rust, and it's quite nice to get everything as Result or Option ... I don't like this mixed error handling in C++ with return codes, exceptions, and optional write-back parameters ...

Comment: What if your column contains " 1984 " with spaces at either end? Is it an integer or a string?

Comment: Well, since I work with output from Excel and Statistica, I don't expect to have such a behaviour - but yes, I should consider this too

Comment: You can also have a look at the unicode library if you have amounts (which are written differently according to the locale). http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/numbers (look at the bottom for a link to an example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use boost lexical_cast. It throws an exception if the cast fails

```
try
{
    number = boost::lexical_cast<int>(your_string);
}
catch (const boost::bad_lexical_cast& exec)
{
    // do something on fail
}
```

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html these results look promising, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should check iteratively whether the number parses 1) as an integer, 2) as a floating point number, and finally 3) as neither. But "parsing" should mean that the entire string is consumed.

Try something like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

bool TryAsInt(const std::string & s, long long int & out)
{
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    return (iss >> out >> std::ws) && (iss.get() == EOF);
}
```

Likewise for floats.

If you don't like using iostreams for this, you can also use `std::strtoll` and `std::strtod` etc. This allows you control over the integer number base, too. For example:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

bool TryAsInt(const std::string & s, long long int & out)
{
    char * e;
    errno = 0;

    out = std::strtoll(s.data(), &e, 0);
    return errno == 0 && s.data() + s.size() == e;
}
```

Then you still have to combine this with logic that checks all fields.

For example:

```
std::vector<string> raw_fields;

long long int n;
double x;

if (std::all_of(raw_fields.begin(), raw_fields.end(),
    [&n](const string & s) { return TryAsInt(s, n); })
{
    // integer case
}
else if (std::all_of(raw_fields.begin(), raw_fields.end(),
    [&x](const string & s) { return TryAsFloat(s, x); })
{
    // floating point case
}
else
{
    // just use raw_fields as-is
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out - but I'll have to run some timing benchmarks comparing boost, stringstreams and stoi.

Comment: @dommynik: If you need performance, then it would be more efficient to perform the raw lexical analysis on your inputs rather than do all the redundant parsing. That's not entirely trivial, but doable.

Answer (score 3):

Use normal std::stoi for it, but be sure to check if the string is fully consumed. E.g.:

```
static bool isIntValue(const std::string& string, int32_t& intValue)
{
    try
    {
        size_t lastChar;
        intValue = std::stoi(string, &lastChar);
        return lastChar == string.size();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This code executes much faster than the std::istringstream solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more type checks have a look at boost [Spirit X3](http://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/).
You could do for instance:

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T, typename RuleType>
bool is_type(std::string const& str, RuleType const& rule, T& val)
{
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    auto beg = std::begin(str);
    auto end = std::end(str);

    auto ret = parse(beg,end, rule, val);
    return ret && (beg==end);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string s1="1.0";
    float v;
    std::cout << s1 << " is int ?   : " << is_type(s1, boost::spirit::x3::int_, v) << "\n";
    std::cout << s1 << " is float ? : " << is_type(s1, boost::spirit::x3::float_, v) << "\n";



    return 0;
}
```

Note: You could specify more strict parsing (have a look here: https://github.com/djowel/spirit_x3/tree/master/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/numeric)

Answer (score -2):

You want to fail for numbers which contain decimal numbers. You can either test for a dot, or test for decimal digits.

```
if (num.find('.') != string::npos || num.find(',') != string::npos)
   cout << "Number is not integer" << endl;
```

Second option:

```
double fnum = std::stod(num);
if (fnum != (long)fnum)
   cout << "Number is not integer" << endl;
```

You should not worry about floating point rounding errors because every integer can be represented precisely as double up to 2^53.

Comment: If int is 32-bit and float too, then a float cannot accurately represent all int values.

Comment: Yes, I've just realized floats hold only 24 bits for integers. Thanks

Comment: `.` isn't the only character that can be in a floating-point literal but not an integer one.  You'd want to rule out `e` and `E`, too.